# How can I keep my livestock from dying

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Originally my farm (sheep and chickens) was at ground level with fences around it. I noticed that when logging into the game the animals would teleport themselves outside the fences. They don't seem to do it if you stay logged in for long periods of time but as soon as you go out and then back in there is potential for it to happen. In an attempt to fix this problem I dug the pen down two blocks deep [image]

This seems to keep them from freeing themselves but now they glitch into the wall and suffocate. At least this what I assume is happening, I've seen them go into the wall and turn a very dark almost black color before, but when I am watching it happen they always pop back out after a second or two. But I am definitely losing them (I used to have many more), and I just found some lime green wool on the ground when I returned back to the pen after spelunking for a while so I know the lime sheep died.

My question is: What design can I use for my pen that will prevent my animals from escaping and keep them from dying randomly as well.

Comment: did you try making a fence 2-3 blocks tall, the glitch could be that that when you log in the fences originally register as 1 block talk rather than 1.5 so the animals could technically jump over them, i'm not sure if the suffocate in a fence

Comment: @MemorX The glitch is well-documented and that's not why it happens. It's because entities load before blocks, giving animals time to move around before the fence exists.